# having file path errors in sublime text with python

Tags: python

Here is the error im getting

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   "/home/corey/Documents/loop.py", line 2, in <module>
    for magician in magicians:
NameError: name 'magicians' is not defined
[Finished in 2.9s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python3 -OO -u "/home/corey/Documents/loop.py"]
[dir: /home/corey/Documents]
[path:
```

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]

Comment: can you provide your code? It seems you are missing the variable `magicians`.

Comment: magicians = ['alice', 'david', 'caroline']
for magician in magicians:
 print(magician)

Comment: these code works fine to me

Comment: show code in question, not in comment.

Comment: You are using the book, python crash course, right?. So there is no air of mystery in it. Now please send the full code in question

Comment: yes I am. I figured it out. thanks guys and girls